# Please explain plane of symmetry

Tags: cis-trans-isomerism

[image: plane of symmetry]

i am getting option (a) but answer is (b) where i am going wrong please help
SO IT IS OPTION A ONLY FOR ME BUT HOW B HAS PLANE OF SYMMETRY PLEASE HELP

Comment: Please [edit](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/108205/edit) in your reasoning as to how did you obtain A and why's B wrong. It is far better to understand a concept than knowing an answer.

Comment: What's to explain? That's right, (a) has a plane of symmetry, and (b) doesn't.

Comment: The meso cmp. must be member of a set with at least *two* optically active stereoisomers.

Comment: Answer (a) is not optically active to begin with so it's not compound "A"!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that after (a) is hydrogenated the result is a meso compound.  But, (a) is also a meso compound before hydrogenation, you can draw a mirror through the double bond; and so (a) misses the first part of the question.  (b) satisfies both parts.